# Apigee: Setting up local usergrid causing problems

Tags: apigee, usergrid

I have downloaded Usergrid to run on my local environment. I am having issues starting up with it though . For starters I am not able to login Usergrid console. I used the default password test/test & superuser/superpassword but I am not able to get into the console. Any suggestions how I can get around this?

On the log I see the following message:

```
29-Nov-2014 11:28:52,413][ERROR][AWT-EventQueue-0] org.apache.usergrid.launcher.Server.getAccessTokenForAdminUser(Server.java:603) Unable to get user: test@usergrid.com
[29-Nov-2014 11:28:52,413][ERROR][AWT-EventQueue-0] org.apache.usergrid.persistence.cassandra.EntityManagerImpl.validate(EntityManagerImpl.java:1760) Unable to load entity: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001
[29-Nov-2014 11:28:52,423][ERROR][AWT-EventQueue-0] org.apache.usergrid.launcher.Server.getAdminUUID(Server.java:615) Unable to get user: test@usergrid.com
[29-Nov-2014 11:28:52,423][ERROR][AWT-EventQueue-0] org.apache.usergrid.persistence.cassandra.EntityManagerImpl.validate(EntityManagerImpl.java:1760) Unable to load entity: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001
[29-Nov-2014 11:28:52,433][ERROR][AWT-EventQueue-0] org.apache.usergrid.launcher.Server.getAccessTokenForAdminUser(Server.java:603) Unable to get user: test@usergrid.com
[29-Nov-2014 11:28:52,433][ERROR][AWT-EventQueue-0] org.apache.usergrid.persistence.cassandra.EntityManagerImpl.validate(EntityManagerImpl.java:1760) Unable to load entity: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001
[29-Nov-2014 11:28:52,443][ERROR][AWT-EventQueue-0] org.apache.usergrid.launcher.Server.getAdminUUID(Server.java:615) Unable to get user: test@usergrid.com
```

-S

Comment: Did you run the setups?  What is on this page:  http://usergrid.incubator.apache.org/docs/deploy-local/

Answer (score 1):

Be sure to create an Organization and an admin user for it.  Nothing happens until that is done.

```
curl -X POST \ -d 'organization=myfirstorg&username=myadmin&name=Admin&email=admin@example.com&password=password' \ http://localhost:8080/management/organizations
```

At this point you will have an Org and Admin User, so you should be good to go.